# Excel - Populate several cells from date span

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

**Background**: I am working on a form for work where project leaders enter the start and end date of planned maintenance work. If it is affecting the customer, we will need to post information to the affected areas where customer is affected, with instructions on one such information post per day of the planned work. In essence, a planned work stretching for 4 total days will require 4 separate info posts. These posts also need the respective date in their respective header.

As such, I have two date fields in my worksheet, where they fill out the start date and time `(YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm)` and end time in the same format. (Below screenshot is from LibreOffice since it's what I have here at home, but the question is for excel.)

Start and end date:

[image: Start and end date]

Desired result:

[image: Desired result]

What I wish to do is on a separate sheet make a dropdown of all separate days inbetween the start and end dates so I can make the dynamic info post headers, but I need the populate the cells with inbetween dates to make the actual dropdown list. As long as I have the populated list, I can do the rest just fine for my purposes.
Result mockup:

[image: Result mockup]

I would absolutely prefer to use a function rather than a macro/VBA, but the only thing I can think of is a long list in the data sheet consisting of `=IF(DAYS(End;Start)+1=x;Date+x;"")` and reading from there ignoring blanks in the dropdown. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Did you mean to say that you want all Dates Between Start and End Date to filter and attach to Drop Down for further Access?

Comment: @RajeshS Yes, I suppose. In the end, I want a dropdown of all dates between and including start and end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `=IF(($B$2+1)<=$C$2,$B$2+1,"")` in B4.

Then `=IF(B4="","",IF((B4+1)<=$C$2,B4+1,""))` in B5, then drag downwards.

Done. ( :

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up doing. The dropdown that refers to this list of dates contains a whole lot of blanks tho, but that's a problem beside my original question so I'm marking this as solved.

Comment: may I know the maximum day difference between start n end that you are looking at?

Comment: Absolutely, I was thinking a maximum of one month. Typically the jobs are over night or a couple of days, but you never know so potential max of one month, maaaybe two.

Comment: Then you may use `if(counta([range])<10,[range1-10],if(counta([range])<20,[range1-20],if(counta([range])<30,[range1-30],[range1-all])))` in data validation range selection.. if it didn't work, try replace  `counta([range]` a cell with that value instead. || just a suggestion to minimize the massive 'blank' thing. ( :